# Prime ideal being maximal ideal and PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Q1. Does there exist an ID R in which every non zero prime ideal of type pR is maximal ideal but R is not PID?

Q2. Does there exist an ID R in which every non zero prime ideal is maximal ideal but R is not PID?

If R is a UFD, then there does not exist such examples. But is it true if R is ID or FD?

Comment: The first question specifies *principal* prime ideals, right? Apparently you mean to specify *nonzero* prime ideals because an integral domain in which $\{0\}$ is maximal is a field.

Comment: right @rschwieb should I edit it?

Comment: you *definitely* need to add "nonzero" before someone posts a trivial answer. You could add a bit more of your own work, if you have it handy, as well.

Comment: @rschwieb sorry had not realised it before. Thanks I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

For question 2, any *Dedekind domain* satisfies these conditions: they're integral domains of Krull dimension $1$. For instance, any ring of algebraic integers is a Dedekind domain, and for such rings being a UFD is equivalent to being principal.

In the particular case of quadratic integers, there are only $9$ imaginary number fields such that their ring of quadratic integers is principal. For real number fields, it is not even known whether there is an infinity of them with a principal ring of integers (it is a conjecture by Gauß).